# Salesforce experience public profile throttle requests

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I have a Lightning Web Component on a public facing experience site.  Anyone know how to throttle LWC APEX API requests only for this profile?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you want to do that. I am guessing you are trying to limit Monthly guest page views.

There is no OOTB solution, if you have a custom domain you can still write something in webmaster tools like Cloudflare allows functions to run when a request is made to domain as otherwise it cannot be done OOTB.